# Example of a $\Bbb Q$-Cartier divisor?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am looking for an example of a $\Bbb Q$-Cartier divisor that is not Cartier. Thanks for your help.

Comment: See Hartshorne example II.6.11.3, for instance.

Comment: Why is this downvoted?